# SVG Rotation of Complex gradient-filled Circle about X-Y axis

Tags: animation, svg, rotation

I'm having some trouble understanding SVG rotations. I've created the following examples to show what I want to do:

- Simple (declarative) SVG rotation animation: http://jsfiddle.net/bcmoney/FrEeA/
- Planet Earth broken rotation attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/bcmoney/EbRb9/
  (cool side effect of using JSfiddle is that you can actually see the Vector Graphics scale as you drag the window size, but I digress)

I just want to rotate it similar to this soccer ball (which is evidence that its not too tough to rotate more complex objects than a simple circle):
[Link](http://xahlee.info/js/soccer_ball_rotating.svg)

Can anyone suggest where to make changes to cause the "Earth" vector graphic to rotate about the 0,0 x-y axis, rather than taking the full radius of the entire object as its rotation axis?

Hopefully its possible to do this declaratively, using only SVG xml markup not any external libraries like Raphael or other fancy tricks (I'm sure I can figure that out, but trying to avoid it).

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty close: http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/8dA9j/ As you haven't drawn the paths centred on the origin, you need to translate the paths so that the globe is centred on the origin. You can then rotate that and wrap all that in a new translation if you don't want the whole thing rotating at the origin.

You should be able to fiddle with the transform="translate(-360,-420)" line to remove the remaining wobble.